# Can't access HTTPS site on IIS 8

Tags: security, ssl, iis, https, webserver

I have web server hosting a site with bindings to HTTP 80 and HTTPS 443.
Some user can't access the HTTPS site and get stuck in the credentials screen, This sames users can access the HTTP site without credentials issues.

I can access the HTTPS site using vpn(Home office), but can't connect to the HTTPS site from the pc in the office.

The authentication method for the site are:

1. Windows Authentication : Enabled
2. ASP Impersonation: Enabled
3. Other methods/options: Disabled

In the logs show this entries:

2021-07-16 21:03:37 111.111.111.111 GET / - 443 - 222.222.222 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/91.0.4472.124+Safari/537.36 - 401 2 5 102

Any advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: A single line of log entry does not help much revealing what might be wrong. You have to work with your domain administrators to collect more information, so as to see what might be wrong with Windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks @LexLi right now I am monitoring the isue. I found the IIS is not passing the user and pass to  the third party app. We will track the authentication process in the web server

Comment: "IIS is not passing the user and pass to the third party app" is quite common. Only under well configured conditions, user credentials can go from browser to IIS and then pass onto a third party. Your domain administrators should be quite familiar with those settings and can help you out.